# How should I type-hint a generic class method that calls another class method to construct an instance of the class?

Tags: python, mypy, typing, type-variables

I'm trying to figure out the type hinting for a couple of abstract classes that I want to use as base classes for classes have a `create` function. Specifically, this is for deserialization typing.

My simple example looks like this

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Type, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")


class A(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def create(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        pass

class B(A, ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def create_b(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def create(cls) -> T:
        return cls.create_b()
```

When I run Mypy against this I get

> error: Incompatible return value type (got "B", expected "T")

I'm confused by this because `B` inherits from `A`, and I thought that `T` more or less represented "any `A`".

I can change the penultimate line to

```py
    def create(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
```

but then I get

> error: "Type[T]" has no attribute "create_b"

What should I be doing to get mypy to pass?

Comment: You did only bound `T` to the general `A`. For the `T` in `B.create` you need a bound of at least `B`.

Comment: Got it. I think that fixes my issue. Feel free to add as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Why provide a concrete definition of `create`, only to have it call a new abstract method?

Comment: In reality `B.create` does more than just return, and I want to consolidate that logic in `B` so consumers don't have to reimplement it.

Answer (score -1):

Since `create` is a class method, the argument `cls` has type `Type[B]`.
This means that the `T` as specified for argument and return types in `create_b` will be resolved to `B` and therefore the expression `cls.create_b()` has type `B`.
This results in the error you get.

The confusing part here is probably that since `B` is a subtype of `A` and `T` is bound to `A`, one might expect that it should be possible to return `B` in `B.create()`.
The problem is however, that `T` will be resolved when `B.create()` is being used in some context and not earlier.
In your example, you implicitly already enforce `T` to be `B`, which can lead to type errors.

As an example, let's say we create the following class and function.

```
class C(A):
    pass


def foo(x: C):
    pass
```

We can now use `B.create()` as an argument of `foo`:

```
foo(B.create())
```

The type checker won't complain here, because it resolves `T` (the generic return type of `create` as `C`, which is perfectly fine, since `T` is bound by `A` and `C` is a subtype of `A`.

Revisiting the function definition of `B.create()`, we can now see that we actually must return the abstract type `T` and not some permissible realization of `T`, such as `B` (or even `A`).

#### TL;DR

You can fix your error by changing the return type of `B.create()`:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls) -> "B":
    return cls.create_b()
```